# vb net: zoom in designer

Tags: vb.net, zooming, scale, designer

I was searching google for a way to size the form and the controls with it and came across something that mentioned Control.scale. How do I use the control.scale method to size everything down to the way I want it.

Also, is there a way I can zoom the form out in the designer. I want to create a 1280X800 form, but my screen is 1024X768. I want to be able to zoom out to see the entire form wile still having it's size be 1280X800.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tablelayout panel` in order to fit your `form` in all `resolutions`.similary a property called `anchor`, which is also need to be assigned for the `controls` inside `tablelayout panel` according to your requirement [top,bottom,left,right] to achieve the same.

By the way you have to use `percentage` for setting the `column's width` and `row's height` in that.

Simply, this way of designing is called as `fluid designing`.

### [Table layout panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx.aspx)

Comment: @user2125978: Or just use anchors (without TableLayoutPanel) - if your UI is not very complex.